# How to use like clause for a value separated with comma in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-like

In my database I have a column where the value is separated by a comma (`firstname,lastname`).

I am trying to search this entire field in where clause using like condition.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT fullname 
from users 
where ( upper( fullname ) like upper('abc, xyz'))
```

Comment: "In my db i have a field separated with comma" - that's possibly your first problem!

Comment: @MitchWheat: not "*possibly*" - definitely

Comment: Do you want to have separate conditions on firstname and lastname?

Comment: no i dont want to have a saperate condition.

Comment: Normalize your data model, then you can do: `where upper(firstname) = 'ABC' and upper(lastname) = 'XYZ'`

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Comment: Change it to `like upper('%abc%,%xyz%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used regexp_like instead of only like and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this- 
It will retrieve field values separated with comma ','

```
     select * from table_name where filedName LIKE %,%;
```

If this is not what you are finding, please eleborate or explain more about your question.

Comment: SELECT fullname from users where ( upper( fullname ) like upper('abc, xyz')) i have a query like this. when i execute it i get no result though abc,xyz is present in fullname field.

Comment: Write query like this-                                                                                 select fullname from users where fullname LIKE abc%,%xyz;

Comment: abc%,%xyz wont it fetch values if abcd,xyz is also present.?

Comment: i think if you need exact same result like abc,xyz then you should use = operator instead of LIKE keyword.

Comment: when i use = operator i am not getting any results.

Comment: yes it will retrieve abcd,xyz also if we are using LIKE keyword.

Comment: what query you are trying to execte using = operator.??

Comment: if i use = operator or like without % i am unable to get the results.

Comment: = operator should retrieve the results. We can't use like keywod without % operator. please post the query you are trying to execute using =

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separate conditions on both `firstname` and `lastname`, you need to split them in your `WHERE` clause

**Test Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (full_name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('Jessica,Alba');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT full_name FROM table_name
WHERE SUBSTR(full_name, 1, (INSTR(full_name, ',', 1) -1)) LIKE '%ss%'
AND SUBSTR(full_name, (INSTR(full_name, ',', 1)) +1) LIKE '%ba%';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7976/4)